# Kafka: Maximal number of partitions inside consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to understand the technical limit in terms of partitions per consumer group in Kafka, especially if subscribing with a wildcard pattern. I have read in many place there is no limit, but I have observed many limitations in real world:

- on consumer groups with 1000+ partitions the SYNCGROUP messages easily exceeds 1 MB (the default max message size), so you need to keep increasing max.message.bytes of the __consumer_offsets topic - if your consumer listens to 10000+ partitions such message would be maybe 50+ MB in size!
- a consumer subscribing using a wildcard pattern will send METADATA requests with topics=NONE, which will put quite some load on the Kafka brokers with thousands of partitions (especially if you use ACLs too), e.g. if you bring up 10 consumers in parallel.

Any guidance on the maximal number of partitions per consumer group would be helpful.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? I would like to say that subscribing to tens of thousands of partitions isn't a good design.

Comment: I‘m totally aware that this pattern is considered bad practice. But especially if you deal with non-experienced users, larger clusters and wildcard patterns such things happen in real live.

Comment: Well, there's a broker setting `group.max.size` for consumers and `max.connections` for all clients. I'm not really sure about partitions

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having large consumer groups as it places a lot of load on your system and cluster. If you're unable to get the throughput you need for your use case, consider something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC).
By using PC, you can process all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes to do the processing.
With PC you could, for example, have 10 partitions for sharding across your broker cluster, and have only 3 PC instances, and still achieve very high throughput - due to how PC breaks down partitions, while ensuring per KEY ordering.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link, but unfortunately it does not answer my question . I'm searching a limit for the number of partitions in a consumer group to share this best practices on the maximal size with my team. For other factors such limits have been shared, e.g. a maximal number of partitions per broker.